# How to custom strapi Admin UI v4?

Tags: strapi

I have tried to change the HomeHeader of the Admin page, but it has no changes.

I copy admin folder in **node_modules/@strapi/admin/admin to my-project/admin** and then I modified **HomeHeader.js** file as the image below:

[image]

I started strapi with the command `yarn strapi develop --watch-admin`, and nothing happened

Please help me to custom this! Thanks

- Strapi Version: 4.0.4
- Operating System: MacOs
- Database: postgres Node
- Version: v14.18.1
- NPM Version: 6.14.15
- Yarn Version: 1.22.10

Answer (score 3):

In Strapi-v3 you can customize the admin panel UI, but in v4 you can't.
there is an [opened issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/12188) in GitHub about this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I almost went crazy trying to override homepage components with custom

Comment: do you advice to downgrade the version of Strapi to v3 just for this?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this requirement of a client.

To replace or customize Strapi admin dashboard home, you can overwrite the file using webpack.

First make sure to install webpack-dev-server in devDependencies.

Create a component file in `src/admin/components/Home.tsx` with basic React component code.

on the file src/admin/webpack.config.js write this code to replace the original Home page.

```
module.exports = (config, webpack) => {
...
  /**
   * Overwrite the dashboard home Component
   */
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /.cache\/admin\/src\/pages\/HomePage\/index\.js/,
      path.resolve(__dirname, "components/Home.tsx")
    )
  );
....

  // Important: return the modified config
  return config;
};
```

then re-build you app.

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Op1: Edit in node_modules and use patch-package to save it (For small change)

Op2: Fork Strapi, edit and commmit. After that use new version strapi instead of default versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In strapi v4 there are only limited customization options compared to v3. Everyone in the community is trying for the same options in Strapi V4.

I have posted a Feature Request to Strapi to at least include this in v5 (which is yet to be release)

**Support my feature request by upvoting https://feedback.strapi.io/feature-requests/p/html-customization-for-admin-panel-pages**